I can't get an collection variable from flow to apex
I'm stuck on something, I did an apex code that gets all the conversion rate dated by an input which is an invocable variable and an output which is in a dedicated class to appear as collection variables defined by the apex, the output comes as
{!opportunityrate} = output ([Response: {"startDate": "2024-03-01", "NextStartDate": "2024-03-04", "conversionRate": "4.959000" }]),
but when I try to get this type of collection as input in another apex, does not appear: the both code is above:
(Sorry, my English isn't that good)
//this is the one that get all conversion rate dated.
global class Taxa_datadas {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Conversion Rates' description='Retrieve and sum conversion rates within a date range')
    public static List<List<Response>> Taxa_datadas(List<InputVar> inputVar) {
        List<List<Response>> outputResponse = new List<List<Response>>();

        // Get the inputs
        Date firstDate = inputVar.get(0).firstDate;
        Date finalDate = inputVar.get(0).finalDate;
        String isoCode = inputVar.get(0).isoCode;

        // Query DatedConversionRate with firstDate and finalDate
        List<DatedConversionRate> conversionRates = [SELECT ConversionRate, StartDate,NextStartDate
                                                     FROM DatedConversionRate 
                                                     WHERE StartDate >= :firstDate
                                                     AND NextStartDate <= :finalDate
                                                     AND isoCode = :isoCode
                                                     ORDER BY StartDate ASC];

        // Initialize list to hold responses
        List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();

        // Add conversion rates to responses list
        for (DatedConversionRate rate : conversionRates) {
            Response response = new Response();
            response.conversionRate = String.valueOf(rate.ConversionRate);
            response.startDate = String.valueOf(rate.StartDate);
            response.NextStartDate = String.valueOf(rate.NextStartDate);
            responses.add(response);
        }

        // Add responses list to outputResponse
        outputResponse.add(responses);

        return outputResponse;
    }
//dedicated class
    public class Response {
    
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable     
        public String conversionRate;
        
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
        public String startDate;
    
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
        public String NextStartDate;
    
}

    public class InputVar {
        @InvocableVariable
        public Date firstDate;

        @InvocableVariable
        public Date finalDate;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String isoCode;
    }
}


//this one is the one that i try to get the collection
 public class Escolhe_data_datada {
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Escolher Taxa de Oportunidades' description='Seleciona taxas de oportunidades ativas para a data de fechamento')
    public static List<responses> escolherTaxaOportunidades(List<InputVar> inputs) {
        
        List<String> taxasDeOportunidades = inputs.get(0).Taxas;
        Date dataFechamento = inputs.get(0).Data_fechamento;
        
        List<responses> resultList = new List<responses>();
        
        // Iterar sobre as taxas de oportunidades
        for (String taxaJson : taxasDeOportunidades) {
            // Parse do JSON para um objeto
            Map<String, Object> taxaMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(taxaJson);
            
            // Obter as datas do objeto
            String startDateString = (String) taxaMap.get('startDate');
            String nextStartDateString = (String) taxaMap.get('NextStartDate');
            Date startDate = Date.valueOf(startDateString);
            Date nextStartDate = Date.valueOf(nextStartDateString);
            
            // Verificar se a data de fechamento está dentro do intervalo
            if (dataFechamento >= startDate && dataFechamento < nextStartDate) {
                // A taxa é válida para o período de fechamento
                responses result = new responses();
                result.Taxa = Double.valueOf((String) taxaMap.get('conversionRate'));
                resultList.add(result);
            }
        }
        
        return resultList;
    }
    public class InputVar {
        @InvocableVariable
        public List<String> Taxas;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public Date Data_fechamento;
    }

    public class responses {
        @InvocableVariable
        public Double Taxa;
    }
}



yeah i reealy dont now why i cant get the collection from the flow , its just dont apear on the input label

the flow gets back from invocable 1 a collection of an apextype but the input to invocable 2 has a property that is a list of strings.  You'll need to transform the results from invocable 1 into a new collection of strings to pass to invocable 2 variable Taxas
